# python list separation by certain condition

Tags: python

every second i'm receiving a data in list form like [40000, 10000]

this is my code

```
def time_price(some_list):
    dPrices = []
    current =  32400 +((some_list[0] - 32400) // 540) * 540
    flag = current + 540
    temp = []

    if some_list[0] < flag:
        temp.append(some_list[1])
    else:
        maxValue = max(temp)
        del temp[:]
        dPrices.append((current, maxValue))
        current =  32400 +((some_list[0] - 32400) // 540) * 540
        flag    = current+540
```

what i'm going to do is organizing the data by some_list[0].

for this i make variable(current) and then put some_list[1] by it.

when certain condition happen, then stop filling temp list and  put max value of
list in dPrices and making next process with temp

but my code doesnot working...

what is the problem?

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: What is the error message? put the error message also,

Comment: Provide sample input and expected output or error

Comment: What is   `flag = current + 540` at the end for? If that is all the function is doing it will be reset each time you call the function so the last flag value id never used

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think he is using it once for each some_list that might not be the problem

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused on how your code is supposed to behave.  The first problem is that your function is not returning any value.  That would normally be fine (although not the best practice) if it just operating on an input.  In this case though you are defining a number of local variables, but never return any value.

So what value do you want to get back from the function?  My guess is `dPrices`, but you might also want `current` and `flag`.  If that is the case, once you get them out, how do you use them?  I am guessing you probably want to feed them back into the function to continue your operations.  If that is the case you can do so with:

```
def time_price(some_list, flag, current):
    ... your operations on variables
        ...
    return dPrices, flag, current
```

Then when you call the function, you can return it to a set of variables.

```
gdPrices, gFlag, gCurrent = def time_price(some_list, gFlag, gCurrent)
```